# Inconsistent Result With Bing Map Silverlight Using Basic Key

Tags: silverlight, dynamics-crm-2011, bing-api, bing-maps

Hi I have used following code but sometime I didnt get the pushpin, I am using Basic key can any one please suggest me.

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Geocode("8800 Lyra Avenue, Columbus, OH 43240", 1);
        Geocode("2137 Birchwood Dr, Redmond,WA 78214,U.S.", 1);
        Geocode("Santa Cruz, Duval Co., TX", 1);
    }
     private void Geocode(string address, int waypointIndex)
    {
        PlatformServices.GeocodeServiceClient geocodingService = new PlatformServices.GeocodeServiceClient("BasicHttpBinding_IGeocodeService");
        geocodingService.GeocodeCompleted += new EventHandler<TestSL.PlatformServices.GeocodeCompletedEventArgs>(geocodingService_GeocodeCompleted);

        PlatformServices.GeocodeRequest request = new PlatformServices.GeocodeRequest();
        request.Credentials = new TestSL.PlatformServices.Credentials();
        request.Credentials.ApplicationId = ((Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.ClientTokenCredentialsProvider)(MyMap.CredentialsProvider)).Token;
        request.Query = address;

        geocodingService.GeocodeAsync(request, waypointIndex);
    }
    public void geocodingService_GeocodeCompleted(object sender, TestSL.PlatformServices.GeocodeCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        MapLayer myMapLayer = new MapLayer();
        MyMap.Children.Add(myMapLayer);
        // create a location collection class
        LocationCollection myLocationColl = new LocationCollection();
        var geoResult = (from r in e.Result.Results
                         orderby (int)r.Confidence ascending
                         select r).FirstOrDefault();
        if (geoResult != null)
        {

            Pushpin myPushPin = new Pushpin();
            // set it to first found location
            myPushPin.Location = new Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.Location(geoResult.Locations[0].Latitude, geoResult.Locations[0].Longitude);
            ToolTipService.SetToolTip(myPushPin, geoResult.DisplayName);
            // add it to location collection
            // which would be used to set the map's bound
            myLocationColl.Add(myPushPin.Location);
            // Add the drawn point to the route layer.                   
            myMapLayer.Children.Add(myPushPin);
        }
    }
```

Sometime i get two pushpin and Sometime I didnt get anything and sometimes i get 1 or 3. can any one please tell me why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

You should geocode all your data ahead of time and store the coordinates. Trying to geocode a bunch of addresses on the fly like this will drive up the number of transactions generated by your application. When using a basic key it can be rate limited if a bunch of requests are made in a short period of time. When the request is rate limited a flag is added to the header of the response to indicate this. This is documented at the bottom half of this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701703.aspx